# Play 1.2.4 framework scheduled mail

Tags: email, playframework-1.x

Is there a way to send scheduled mail in play framework 1.2.4?

Even if it is job scheduling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Schedule Job of Play framework. Please check below link for more details.

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/jobs